# Need clarification on insert API call in Zoho crm

Tags: javascript

I got the below error while trying store contact form value to zoho.

```
My xml code:
------------
When i give the name and email address as hard coded it will works fine:
var xmlDoc = '<Contacts><row no="1"><FL val="First Name">Peter</FL><FL val="Last Name">jhon</FL><FL val="Email">peter.r@gmail.com</FL></row></Contacts>';


While concatenating it throw error
Error:
<message>Unable to parse XML data</message>

var xml = '<Contacts><row no="1"><FL val="First Name">' + contact.firstName + '</FL><FL val="Last Name">' + contact.lastName + '</row></Contacts>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field Label close tag for lastName was missing

```
var xml = '<Contacts><row no="1"><FL val="First Name">' + contact.firstName + '</FL><FL val="Last Name">' + contact.lastName + '</FL></row></Contacts>';
```